# epxorting an array of objects from a js file to another

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I have js file called "elements" with inside only an array of objects, im' trying to export this array inside a sedon file app.js where i will work with the data inside the array, but import export doesn't work and i really don't understand.

I export the array of objects called "groupOfElements" from the file elements.js:

```
const groupOfElements = [
];

export default groupOfElements;
```

I import the file inside another file app.js:

```
"use strict"

import groupOfElements from "./elements.js";

console.log(groupOfElements);
```

All the files are at the same level in the folder, the html too.
Than i add the file app.js in the html as a module:

```
        </div>
        <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I receive Nothing, to console.log, no errors.

I tried to remove the type module but i have the error
`Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I also tried different type of import export, using default directly on the array, also tried to don't use default importing the {groupOfElements}, but nothing works..

Update: i tiped a simple function that console log "hello", importing this function instead of the array, but it doesn't work too. .looks like the problem is in the import itself but i still can't find the reason

Comment: Can you confirm the JS file is being run-- try logging something else, like `Hello World`

Comment: the main file app.js run, if i remove the type module and i paste the array directly inside the file everything works perfectly, the problem, even if i don't remove the array from the main file, when i assign the type module in the html and try to import the file everythink stops work

Comment: Ok, great, can you make sure the app.js file is accessible by going to `yourwebsite/app.js` or in the same directory as that html page

Answer (score 0):

It works fine and It shows your code is ok, but are you using some kind of packages like `webpack` or `react` or anything similar?

there are other possibilities like remove `'use strict'` and try again or

write something else after import like `'import x from ./elements.js'`(because it is a default export the name doesn't really matter.)

and one more thing you should try this on browser not node.js terminal...

Comment: i was working on the browser preview directly in VSC but without any pakage, all the code is native, i tried now to open it on firefox and chrome also removing the strict mode, still doesn't work..

Comment: can you upload a image from your result on firefox with the code as same as above with no change? @Ripra